# FileContentResult works, but downloading to byte array doesn't

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to convert HTML to a PDF file.

I have the following controller:

```
    public ActionResult Offer([FromBody] DocumentTemplateInvoiceViewModel vm)
    {
        return this.Pdf(nameof(Offer), vm, "test.pdf");
    }
```

When I do a POST here, I get back the file and it can open. Happy days!

However, if I try to do the following:

```
    var termsClient = new RestClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostingUrl"]);
    var termsRequest = new RestRequest("/Document/Offer", Method.POST);
    termsRequest.AddJsonBody(vm);
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm);
    var termsBytes = termsClient.DownloadData(termsRequest);
    File.WriteAllBytes("LOCALPATH",termsBytes );
```

The file is corrupt, and I cannot open the PDF. It has some size, so it stores some bytes. Probably just not stored correctly :D

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Why is the FileContentResult from my controller working, but when I download the data it's corrupt?

Comment: Check the raw requests. Chances are the two requests are asking for two different content types.

Comment: Since the question was resolved in a way that is unlikely to be helpful to anyone else in the future, I refunded your bounty and am closing it as not reproducible. If you agree that there's nothing here that would be useful to others, feel free to delete. (You should be able to delete it yourself. You might have to unaccept your own answer. I don't remember what the system allows, exactly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I'm a ****ing idiot, and the problem was something completely different. The endpoint simply returned a 404 error, which was just downloaded and wrapped into a file (which obviously gave a corrupt PDF file).

So this code works perfectly. Looking at the requests in Fiddler quickly showed the problem.

Comment: Yeah that can happen. :) Hence the *check the raw requests suggestion*. Live and learn. I've been there

Answer (score 2):

you have your questions marked as MVC so I'm going to try to respond as an MVC application.

The REST objects seem to indicate WEB.API but maybe I am wrong. :)

If you're talking about FileContentResult then I suggest putting in the ContentType.

```
var contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf;
```

Then load the FileContentResult like this:

```
var fcr = new FileContentResult(ms.ToArray(), contentType); //NOTE: Using a File Stream Result will not work.
fcr.FileDownloadName = FileName;
```

I see you are using PDF generation so here is the example I used to generate FileContentResult for PDF:

```
    public FileContentResult CreatePdfFileContentResult()
    {
        var contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Create an instance of the document class which represents the PDF document itself.
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
            // Create an instance to the PDF file by creating an instance of the PDF 
            // Writer class using the document and the filestrem in the constructor.
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);

            if (OnPdfMetaInformationAdd != null)
                OnPdfMetaInformationAdd(document, DataSource);

            // Open the document to enable you to write to the document
            document.Open();

            if (OnPdfContentAdd != null)
                OnPdfContentAdd(document, DataSource);
            else throw new NotImplementedException("OnPdfContentAdd event not defined");

            // Close the document
            document.Close();
            // Close the writer instance
            writer.Close();

            var fcr = new FileContentResult(ms.ToArray(), contentType); //NOTE: Using a File Stream Result will not work.
            fcr.FileDownloadName = FileName;                
            return fcr;
        }
    }
```